# Programmatically locking and unlocking the screen in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, locking, screen

I'm new in Xcode.

In my magic app,I want to lock and immediately unlock the screen,how to do the action?

Example code would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with official iPhone sdk. But as you are saying that this is magic (or fun) app I suggest you create animation in image frames and run that.. (if you just want to show the animation to user).

There is no way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot lock and unlock iPhone programmatically ,But you can show  slide to unlock and lock animation inside your app,
Have a look over this example code ,It shows lock and unlock animation

https://github.com/iosdeveloper/SlideToCancel

https://github.com/mattlawer/MBSliderView